# ExpressJS prevent my app from being hacked

Tags: node.js, security, express, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am writing an app that will give user1's money to user2, if user1 agrees that user2 completed a task successfully.

I have several ideas on how to go about this, but am worried about security. Most likely I am not understanding this subject as much as I should and am hoping for advice.

One method is to listen if user1 is happy with user2's job completion.

Example Express code saving data to a Firebase DB:

```
app.post('/general/something', function(serverReq, serverRes) {
    var data = serverReq.body;

    var ref = db.ref("stuff/"+data.userOneId).update({
        isHappy: true
    });
    serverRes.send("Posted");

});
```

Then I could check if the user is happy in the DB and then send user2 user1's money.

However, it seems as if anyone (especially user2) could just POST DATA (user1's ID) to my server at "/general/something" and receive userone's money.

We can assume that user2 knows user1's Firebase userID. This is because I need the users to be able to reference each other and an userID is the only way that I've found with Firebase (without giving the other user's email address out).

What is the best way of completing this task?

Comment: You need to cryptographically secure your API. In addition to providing their id, they need to also send something that proves that they are in possession of the password for the account.

Comment: @ElanHamburger Where can I learn more about securing my API in this manner? Would I not be able to use Firebase Auth anymore?

Comment: You could use Firebase Auth. You'll probably want something like [token-based authentication](https://scotch.io/tutorials/the-ins-and-outs-of-token-based-authentication) which I believe Firebase provides an API for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @ElanHamburger I am able to fix the problem using tokens with Firebase (https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/verify-id-tokens).